# How to append to an anchor's href attribute with JavaScript but not affect query string?

Tags: javascript

I have some links (they are in an array, not `a` elements)...

- `http://example.com`
- `http://example.com?bob=true`
- `http://example.com?sandy=true&bob=false`

I want to append something after the `.com` but before the start of the query string.

#### Example

- `http://example.com/search/results`
- `http://example.com/search/results?bob=true`
- `http://example.com/search/results?sandy=true&bob=false`

What is the best way?

#### Update

I answered my own question, however if my solution can be improved (or you can see some problem with it) please do post your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this...

```
var append = '/search/results';

anchor.href = anchor.href.replace(/(\?|$)/, append + '$1');
```

I thought I could omit the parenthesis and just back reference with `$0`, but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: In Javascript (well, at least Mozilla and Chrome), `$&` will insert the entire match into the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'http://example.com/search/results?sandy=true&bob=false';
var append = '/foo/path';
alert(a.pathname + append + a.search);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/sYxYg/

Comment: @alex sorry, the property is called `pathname`. My screwup. Anyway, fixed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, +1. I was going to do it this way, but then decided I didn't want to create elements and then access their properties (even if they weren't going to ever appear in the page). This however looks like the most *correct* way to do it. I'm interested in what you think.

Comment: @alex - this is how I would do it, because I do not understand regexes well enough that I am totally comfortable using them. I would use the above if only for the sake of *not* using a regex, but that's just me :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest pure regex solution I came up with

```
function urlappend(url, append) {
  return url.replace(/(?=\?)|$/, append);
}


urlappend('http://example.com?bob=true', '/search/results');
//returns "http://example.com/search/results?bob=true"

urlappend('http://example.com', '/search/results')
//returns "http://example.com/search/results"
```

For the regex curious, `(?=\?)` matches the the position between the first `?` and the character before it.

As to whether this is the "proper" way, that is subjective. I'd say if the links you are dealing with are just strings and not nodes, this way is better. If they are already links, use karim79's method.